# Extract first word from a varchar column and reverse it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following  data in my table

```
id nml               
-- ----------------- 
1  Temora sepanil    
2  Human Mixtard     
3  stlliot vergratob
```

I need to get the result by extracting first word in column `nml` and get its last `3` characters with reverse order

That means output should be like

```
nml               reverse 
----------------- ------- 
Temora sepanil    aro     
Human Mixtard     nam     
stlliot vergratob toi
```

Answer (score 1):

You use PostgreSQL's [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) to achieve desired output

in this case am using `split_part`,`right`,`reverse` function

```
select reverse(right(split_part('Temora sepanil',' ',1),3))
```

output:

```
aro
```

so you can write your query in following format

```
select nml
      ,reverse(right(split_part(nml,' ',1),3)) "Reverse" 
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Split `nml` using `regexp_split_to_array(string text, pattern text [, flags text ])` refer [Postgres Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) for more info.
2. Use `reverse(str)` (refer [Postgres Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)) to reverse the first word form previous split.
3. Use `substr(string, from [, count])` (refer [Postgres Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)) to select first three letters of the reversed test

Query

```
SELECT 
    nml,
    substr(reverse(regexp_split_to_array(nml, E'\\s+')[0]),3) as reverse
FROM
    MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX`, `RIGHT` and `REVERSE` function

here's the syntax

```
  REVERSE(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(nml , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', nml) - 1),3))
```

**sample:**

```
  SELECT REVERSE(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(nml , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', nml) - 1),3)) AS 'Reverse' 
  FROM TableNameHere
```